# How to update a ListView when Binding Changes

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, inotifypropertychanged

I have a ListView in my Xaml-Code which i'd like to update, when its Binding is changing.
I read something about implementing an INotifyPropertyChanged, but I'm not realy familliar with how to do this.

My ListView in Xaml:

```
<ListView IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    x:Name="itemListView"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
    TabIndex="1"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Margin="-10,-10,0,0"
    Padding="120,0,0,60"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectionChanged="ItemListView_SelectionChanged"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RepVSmallIcon70ItemTemplate}" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource JobListViewItemStyle}" 
    IsRightTapEnabled="False" 
    ItemClick="itemListView_ItemClick" />
```

My itemsViewSource Resource:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="itemsViewSource" Source="{Binding Items}"/>
```

My Items in c#: [EDIT: wrong class before]

```
//public class JobDataGroup : repVReportsDataCommon 
public class JobDataGroup : repVReportsDataCommon, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Func<ServiceJobItem, bool> _predicate;

    public JobDataGroup(String uniqueId, String title, String subtitle, String imagePath, String description, Func<ServiceJobItem, bool> predicate)
        : base(uniqueId, title, subtitle, imagePath, description)
    {
        _predicate = predicate;
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public int JobCount
    {
        get { return this.Items.Count(); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ServiceJobItem> Items
    {
        get 
        {
            //[EDIT: changed from IEnumerable to ObservableCollection
            //return repVReportsDataSource.GetJobItems().Where(_predicate); 

            ObservableCollection<ServiceJobItem> collection = new ObservableCollection<ServiceJobItem>(repVReportsDataSource.GetJobItems().Where(_predicate));
            return collection;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ServiceJobItem> TopItems
    {
        // Provides a subset of the full items collection to bind to from a GroupedItemsPage
        // for two reasons: GridView will not virtualize large items collections, and it
        // improves the user experience when browsing through groups with large numbers of
        // items.
        //
        // A maximum of 12 items are displayed because it results in filled grid columns
        // whether there are 1, 2, 3, 4, or 6 rows displayed
        get { return this.Items.Take(12); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your items return as `ObservableCollection` and class `ServiceJobItem` needs to implement
**[INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)** interface, so that ListView notifies when a change has been made..

Comment: class ServiceJobItem was wrong, now it's the correct class.
I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged to JobDataGroup, but what do you mean with return as ObservableCollection?

Comment: ObservableCollection<JobDataGroup> Items

Comment: Is it possible to combine this with IEnumerable? like:
IEnumerable, ObservableCollection<JobDataGroup> Items

Comment: You can convert to ObservableCollection via constructor. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx

Comment: I did all the changes. also do not get any errors, but my ListView does not Refresh after deleting one of my Items. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your return type  of items is still IEnumerable

Comment: actually it is not, but i did not update my code... might it be, i need an ipropertychangedeventhandler etc.?